# Learning OR gate through gradient descent

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to make my program learn OR logic gate using neural network and gradient descent algorithm. I took additional input neuron as -1 so that I can adjust threshold of neuron for activation later. currently threshold is simply 0.
Here's my attempt at implementation

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from numpy import *
def pcntrain(inp, tar, wei, eta):
    for data in range(nData):
        activation = dot(inp,wei)
        wei += eta*(dot(transpose(inp), target-activation))
        print "ITERATION " + str(data)
        print wei
    print "TESTING LEARNED ALGO"
    # Sample input
    activation = dot(array([[0,0,-1],[1,0,-1],[1,1,-1],[0,0,-1]]),wei)
    print activation
nIn = 2
nOut = 1
nData = 4
inputs = array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
target = array([[0],[1],[1],[1]])
inputs = concatenate((inputs,-ones((nData,1))),axis=1) #add bias input = -1
weights = random.rand(nIn +1,nOut)*0.1-0.05 #random weight 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pcntrain(inputs, target, weights, 0.25)
```

This code seem to produce output which does not seem like an OR gate. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this **is** an OR gate, if you correct your testing data to be

```
activation = dot(array([[0,0,-1],[1,0,-1],[1,1,-1],[0,1,-1]]),wei)
```

(your code has 0,0 twice, and never 0,1) it produces

```
[[ 0.30021868]
 [ 0.67476151]
 [ 1.0276208 ]
 [ 0.65307797]]
```

which, after calling round gives

```
[[ 0.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]]
```

as desired.

However, you do have some minor errors:

- you are running 4 iterations of the gradient descent (main loop), furthermore it comes from the fact that you use number of inputs to specify that - this is incorret, there is no relation between number of "reasonable" iterations and number of points. If you run 100 iterations you end up with closer scores

.

```
[[ 0.25000001]
 [ 0.75      ]
 [ 1.24999999]
 [ 0.75      ]]
```

- your model is linear and has linear output, thus you cannot expect it to output exactly 0 and 1, the above result (0.25, 0.75 and 1.25) is actually the optimal solution for this kind of model model. If you want it to converge to nice 0/1 you need sigmoid in the output and consequently different loss/derivatives (this is still a linear model in the ML sense, you simply have a squashing function on the output to make it work in correct space).
- you are not using "tar" argument in your function, instead, you refer to global variable "target" (which have the same value, but this is an obvious error)

Comment: Great answer , can you tell me how you got matrix  [[ 0.] [ 1.] [ 1.] [ 1.]] ?

Comment: I imported numpy as np and called np.round() on your scores